# Tecla TAB en sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3

Estoy editando código usando **sublime text 3** y me molesta que al pulsar la tecla TAB me cambie la palabra sin permitirme seleccionar entre una lista de sugerencias (combobox) o que me de un salto de lineas, cualquiera de las dos opciones me parece más cómoda

¿Que debo escribir en **Setting user** para cambiar este comportamiento o que plugin lo soluciona?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no está relacionado con programación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que ir a Preferences -> Settings y dentro de tu settings pisar el valor del setting `tab_completion` (que viene por defecto en `true`)..

Si eso no funciona, puedes probar modificando la familia de settings que empieza con `auto_complete`. En particular, para tu caso, puedes ver qué efecto tiene apagar o encender `auto_complete_commit_on_tab`.

Si jugar con esas opciones no te da el resultado deseado, hay una manera de personalizar qué ocurre exactamente apretando TAB, usando un archivo `.sublime-completions`. No tengo experiencia en la sintaxis de ese archivos porque nunca he necesitado cambiarlo, así que en ese caso sólo puedo referirte a la sección exacta en la [documentación sobre autocompletions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html).

Comment: Gracias a tu respuesta pude dar con el comando 
// Set to true to insert spaces when tab is pressed
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true

Comment: Otro ejemplo más de que las familias de settings de Sublime están desperdigadas en todas partes de la configuración ;D